# How to render different element in the same page keeping all other things same in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a 3 tabs `Account Information`, `Address Book`, and `Payment Options` like this,

```
function AccountDetails() {
  return (
    <div className="account__details">
      <AccountDetailsTabs>
        <div label="Account Information">
          <AccountInformation></AccountInformation>
        </div>
        <div label="Address Book">
          <AddressBook></AddressBook>
        </div>
        <div label="Payment Options">
          <PaymentOptions></PaymentOptions>
        </div>
      </AccountDetailsTabs>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, when clicked in the Account Information Tab, it renders the `AccountInformation` component

```
import React from "react";
import "./AccountInformation.css";
function AccountInformation() {
  return (
    <div className="account__information">
      <div className="account__information__instruction">
        Please update your personal account details, update your address book or
        change your email setting here.
      </div>
      <div className="account__information__container">
        <div className="userDetails">
          <span>
            {" "}
            <strong>First Name:</strong>{" "}
          </span>
          <span>Aman</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="account__information__buttons row justify-content-between">
        <div className="edit__button__container col-6">
          <button className="edit__button">EDIT</button>
        </div>
        <div className="changepassword__button__container col-6">
          <button className="changepassword__button">CHANGE PASSWORD</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AccountInformation;
```

The image below illustrates it,
[image]

As I am inside the `Account Information` tab, inside this tab there are `EDIT` & `CHANGE PASSWORD` buttons. 
Now, when I click on the `EDIT` or `CHANGE PASSWORD` buttons the tab should render the `EdIT` component keeping all things in the page same. How can I do that? 
I am known to the `react-router` but I don't think this is the good practice using react-router here because there are many other components in the page.

When clicked on one of the button, it should give the following result.
[image]

It would be even great, if you could give link from reactjs official doc to know more about it. Thanks.

Comment: Conditionally show the edit thing when the edit button is clicked. Maintain a state for that in your component. What did you try so far?

Comment: The thing is I am the begineer, I just wanted to know if there is more proper way of doing that because I have to add some more dynamic content rather than just edit and change password. Inside edit and change password, some more pages needs to be rendered. 
So, is if else a good way to do that?

Comment: Thanks, @RameshReddy at least I got an idea of what I can try.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the two sections different components. If you have a component that isn't changing or is the background/backdrop, you could make it the parent. Or you could make them siblings with another component wrapping around both